# Takes too long for any browser to load at the first time

Tags: linux, chrome, browser

I have Gentoo(4.14.83) with dwm as my DE.

I've tried about 6 browsers and every one of them, as I start it right after the boot up, may load only after 30 seconds and up to 100 seconds.

I use Google Chrome. So if I start it from the terminal, it outputs

> getrandom indicates that the entropy pool has not been initialized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers mainly use `/dev/random`(random), as `/dev/urandom`(pseudorandom) isn't considered to be trusted(but as man page random(4) points out, it shouldn't be so).

As it turns out, my laptop has neither [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) nor [DRNG](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide) to efficiently generate random numbers, causing anyone who needs random numbers right after the boot to wait until enough entropy has been gathered. Thus, it has to generate random numbers from things like keyboard, mouse, fan, etc. Meaning you can speed up this process of entropy(random numbers) generation by moving your mouse or typing on the keyboard. It's possible to check available entropy with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`.

If Chrome just used `urandom` instead of `random` there would be no such problem. But it can be easily fixed by feeding `random` from `urandom`:

1) Install **rng-tools**

2) Run `sudo rngd -o /dev/random -r /dev/urandom` before you start your browser, say, in `~/.xinitrc`